# TCL, WMI and twapi

Tags: wmi, tcl

I am sorry if this is a double post.  I thought I posted this question yesterday, but cannot find it.

We are going to start the process of changing our network numbering scheme from `192.168.88.0/24` to `10.0.1.0/24`.  There are approximately 50 devices on our network.  To avoid having to visit each workstation individually, I would like to change the network settings using TCL and twapi if possible.

Is it possible to query a remote workstation using twapi?  All of the information I have found leads me to believe it is possible using the comm module.  However, I have not found an example or found the right combination to make the two work together.

Is it possible to change network settings on a workstation using TCL, twapi and WMI?  From what I have read about twapi, it is possible to query WMI, but I have not seen any mention of the possibility of changing settings.

If there is a better tool for this, I am open to suggestions.  TCL is the language my predecessor was using and I am trying to keep things the same as they are since others outside of IT somewhat understand what is going on.

Comment: If you are not yet using DHCP, then now might be a good time to start using that. If you are, just change the DHCP server settings.

Answer (score 1):

The better tool for this is DHCP.

Assuming you have a domain, you can set this with a GPO that you push out to all your clients.  If not, you can use a tool like psexec, or WMI queries, to set the remote computers to pick up their addresses and network settings from a DHCP server.  The CLI commands to tell your computers to pick up their IP address and DNS servers from DHCP would look something like:

> netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" source=dhcp
>
> netsh interface ip set dns name="Local Area Connection" source=dhcp

Come to think of it, you could even set those commands in a start up script or similar and automatically deploy it to all your computers with minimal effort.

Setting up a Windows DHCP server is pretty easy (almost self explanatory) and easy to find tutorials for online.

Comment: Not to mention, if you have 50 computers you should already have Active Directory, DNS and DHCP in the mix somewhere.

Comment: @MichaelHampton  Right, but if everyone already did, guys like me wouldn't be able to charge a few grand for the 15 minutes of actual work it takes setting it up. =D